# cannot import name X from module

Tags: python

Edit: The problem was solved. There was another `cmd.py` in the python search path. Thank you @Barmar!

I wanted to divide my chunky python script into separate modules but I have encountered an error when importing. For some reasons, it even fails to import a very simple function named Hi() from a very simple script.

I checked with Linter and it doesn't find any problem with it. The error always comes up on runtime. Any solutions?

gamemode.py:

```
from samp import decode
from samp import SetGameModeText
from cmd import Hi
import s
import sqlite3


Hi()
```

cmd.py:

```
def Hi():
    return print("Hi")
```

*(This is the whole script)*

Output:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Hi' from 'cmd'
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the only `cmd.py` in your python search path?

Comment: You're right! @Barmar I just renamed my `cmd.py` into something else and it did the trick. Yeah, it looks like there's a duplicate script in the search path.